# How can I get and set style properties of an object that come from a class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple animation function that simulates a button being pushed, by varying the width:

```
function bPress(b) {
  var w = (parseFloat(b.style.width)*0.96);
  if (b.style.width.substr(-1)=="%") {
    var s ="%";
  }
  else {
    var s = "em";
  }
    b.style.width = w +s;
    b.onmouseup = function () {
      w = (parseFloat(b.style.width)/0.96);
      b.style.width = w+s;
    // etc.
}
```

This was working well until  I started cleaning up my code and changed inline CSS style declarations to classes. I previously had, for example:

```
<div style= 'height: 1.5em; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: 0.2em; font: inherit; font-weight:bold' onclick='checkSave("continue")' onmousedown='bPress(this)'>Continue</div>
```

I moved the CSS parts to a new class:

```
.response_button {
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  font: inherit;
  font-weight:bold
}
```

... avoiding repetition and of course simplifying the div tags.
But the animations stopped working. After some experimenting, I eventually came up with a temporary solution by moving the width back into an inline style declaration. But this seems wrong.

So 2 questions:

1. Why does this.style.width not work if the width is declared inside a class?
2. Is there a way to get and set a div's properties if they are declared inside a class?

**Edit:** For completeness, using nick zoum's answer, here is the modified bPress function:

```
function bPress(b) {
  var w_px = window.getComputedStyle(b).width;
  var w_int = (parseInt(w_px));
  b.style.width = Math.round(w_int * 0.96) + "px";
  b.onmouseup = function () {
    b.style.width = w_px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to put a `;` after `width: 100%` ?

Comment: @Huangism Yes I did but only in the example. I had actually removed width from my code when I moved it back to inline, and forgot the ; when I added it here. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getComputedStyle` to get all of the calculated style properties of an element.

```js
var dom = document.querySelector("#foo");

console.log(getComputedStyle(dom).backgroundColor);
```

```css
#foo {
  background-color: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it. Is there a similar setComputedStyle function?

Comment: @Thailandian There is no `setComputedStyle`, you can just do `dom.style.width = "20px"` though. so i guess there is.

Comment: Thanks nick zoum it works and actually simplifies the animation function as well. I don't usually use px as I scale everything to the window/screen size. But I realised that it doesn't matter if getComputedStyle returns px. I just use px internally within the bPress function.